# How to arrange the string collection in reverse order and it must be case insensitive

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I am trying to order my collection in reversed order, and also case insensitive

This is what I have tried to do so far:

```
Collections.sort(obj,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

**Input:**

```
varun,akash,shakshi,gowtham,VARUN
```

**Output:**

```
akash,gowtham,shashi,varun,VARUN
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: please update you rquestion - not the comments

Comment: ok sorry for that.... when the collection is in the order of .... varun,akash,shakshi,gowtham,VARUN the output for descending order and case sensitive will be ..akash,gowtham,shashi,varun,VARUN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.reversed()`.

*Examples*

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("varun", "akash", "shakshi", "gowtham", "VARUN");

list.sort(null); // Natural order: [VARUN, akash, gowtham, shakshi, varun]
System.out.println(list);

list.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); // [akash, gowtham, shakshi, VARUN, varun]
System.out.println(list);

list.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.reversed()); // [VARUN, varun, shakshi, gowtham, akash]
System.out.println(list);

list.sort(Collator.getInstance().reversed()); // [VARUN, varun, shakshi, gowtham, akash]
System.out.println(list);
```

<sup>*The first sort placed "VARUN" before "varun". Since the other sorts considers them equal, they retain that order for the rest.*</sup>

Quoting javadoc of [`CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER):

> Note that this Comparator does *not* take locale into account, and will result in an unsatisfactory ordering for certain locales. The java.text package provides *Collators* to allow locale-sensitive ordering.

The last example shows how to use [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html). The example uses the JVM's default locale. Use e.g. `Collator.getInstance(Locale.US)` to specify a specific locale.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like as below:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("car");
list.add("apple");
list.add("kite");
list.add("banana");

list.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.reversed());
```